# Want to delete Chrome history but retain data from one site only

Tags: google-chrome, history, browser-cache

I have some mystery issue with something in my Chrome data that affects certain sites. It only affects Chrome and one profile so I have narrowed it down to there.

I get an error like this:
"Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.abcdef.html" on this server.
Reference #18.562fc017.1654500260.2af3b4fb"

It looks to me it's running through some proxy but I certainly can't find it if it is.

The simple solution is to wipe Chrome clean on that profile, history, cookies, cache, etc. But I need to retain the data saved locally for one particular site.

I know this is in the db where the history and site data are stored, but I don't want to copy back over the entire db, just the data for that one site. In Chrome Developer Tools, I can easily find the entry in the DB, but the only command there is to clear it, not to back it up or retore it to a new db later. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not supply built-in tools for selectively deleting history,
so you will need to do it yourself using third-party tools.

The Chrome history is stored for Windows in the folder
`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`,
and for the Mac in
`/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`.

It is found inside an SQLite database file named `History`
(no file extension),
specifically in an SQL table named `keyword_search_terms`.
For URL predictions, the table is called 'urls'.

For doing modifications, you will need
an SQLite database utility such as:
[DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/),
[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/),
[DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/)
or
[SQLite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) for OS X.

You will need to use one of the above tools to run an SQL DELETE command
for all the other websites except the one you want to keep.
Or alternatively, SELECT and EXPORT the history for this website,
for importing back later on, according to the capabilities that are
available in the SQL tool that you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with DBeaver, appreciate the links.

I think I may have found the issue, I think it was a script running from TamperMonkey that I had forgotten about. But I want to get that site data backed up regardless and inject it into Chrome history on another PC.